# ASP.net Core with React.js - Shopify Proxy page

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, shopify

I have created a "ASP.net Core with Rect.js" project that I am trying to use with Shopify's [App Proxies](https://shopify.dev/apps/online-store/app-proxies). I have set up the proxy are per Shopify instructions, but when I when I go to the proxied page. I get a blank screen and 404 errors for .ccs and .js files.

[image]

I have tried adding this to Program.cs, but it does not work

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp/build/static"))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Was missing `"homepage": "the_page_url"` in package.json